# style sheet table class test everything works but cellborders have vanished

Tags: css

I'm trying to replace an inline style with a style sheet

```
<table width="100%" border="6" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="6"  bgcolor="#D3B696" >
```

with

with style sheet

```
.test {
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: separate ;
    width: 720px ;
    border: ridge ;
    border-width: 6px;
    background-color: #D3B696 ;
    border-spacing: 3px ;  padding: 6px;
}
```

all works apart from cell borders have vanished

Comment: You should add borders for cells. .test td

Comment: if you want to apply your given style on table put table instead of .test in css

Comment: Should that be `border-type` instead of `border:ridge` ?

Answer (score 0):

To add cell borders you need to add css rules for the `td` elements in your table. See the `.test td` rule set below and note the space between `.test` and `td`. The space means you are selecting all `td` elements that are descendants of elements containing the `.test` class.

```css
.test {
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: separate;
  width: 720px;
  border: ridge;
  border-width: 6px;
  background-color: #D3B696;
  border-spacing: 3px;
  padding: 6px;
}
.test td {
  border: ridge;
  border-width: 6px;
}
```

```html
<table class="test">
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks  hadnt appreciated borders  only referes to outer table unlike html inline which includes cells   now i have borders  but one to each cell

Comment: Hooray  with border groove its look almost the same as the inline code

Comment: one last problem <table class="test" dosnt rspond to <center>

Comment: Have a look here https://www.granneman.com/webdev/coding/css/centertables/ for methods to center a table using CSS